# How to use ".zsh" files?

Tags: zsh, configuration

This might be a very silly question, but how to use `.zsh` files?

For example, here is a gist [`system-wide-clipboard.zsh`](https://gist.github.com/welldan97/5127861)

> Zsh copy & paste system wide for OS X, like in emacs

I do understand I can simply copy its contents to `~/.zshrc`, but maybe it is possible to use this file directly, that is, to start Zsh with `system-wide-clipboard.zsh` and not with `.zshrc`? Or link this file from within `.zshrc` so that it will be loaded automatically?

Comment: "Or link this file from within .zshrc?" ? `. /path/to/system-wide-clipboard.zsh`?

Comment: @muru I mean "to link this file from within `.zshrc` so that it will be loaded automatically". That is, you open Zsh, Zsh automatically loads `.zshrc`, and `.zshrc` automatically loads `system-wide-clipboard.zsh`. The same as `source $VIM/foo.vim` in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: ".zshrc automatically loads system-wide-clipboard.zsh" => that's what `. /path/to/system-wide-clipboard.zsh` will do (or `source` instead of `.`, if you prefer that)